# Recover 7zip password with partial password matching

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, recovery

I encrypted some files using 7z with AES-256 + file name encryption. The compression level was Ultra, method: LZMA. The password I regularly use is 16 digits. Now the file is not opening. I guess one of the letters in the password was replaced by accident (since I had the "show password" ticked on, there was no chance of confirming the password while I set it).

Is there a software which will allow to check and recover passwords in 7zip archives using a partial match? I had recovered a 8 digit windows xp password using a software called sam-something(samcrack or ) several years before but by a partial match. 
Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not the same. You can't recover a part of the 7zip password.
Since you encryted the files with a preshared key (your password), you would have to guess the whole password, not just a part of it.
You are gonna do a bruteforce attempt on it. Try googling around for some 7zip bruteforce tools, maybe rarcrack can help? 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-shared_key

The samcrack only worked because of DES used in the older versions of windows (LANMAN) password database, where the password is divided up into two 7-byte DES hashes, creating a max of 14 characters, and also very easy to crack. You can't do that on newer versions of windows. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM_hash